# In pymysql of python can I keep a connection object for next use?

Tags: python, pymysql

All tutorials told me database connection is a precious resource.We must close it after do some operations on it.And reopen it when we want do another thing.But I only find out a property(open) that indicate the connection status.

It means I need create connection object for every query|update|delete?
If I won't create connection for every operation （code like below） and how safely destroy the connection?

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='password',
                             db='blog',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = "SELECT * from categories"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    connection.close()

#do other things ..............................
#maby return here and do not execute below
#occur error below

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = "SELECT * from categories"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
```

Comment: You can keep it for multiple queries but if you're using threads you should check its threadsafety level (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety).

Answer (score 0):

Normally your program opens a database connection and keeps it open until the program finishes. Creating/opening a connection is an expensive operation so normally you just want to keep it open for the duration of your program. During the creation of a connection the database has to allocate resources for that connection. If you are going to open and close a connection for every operation this will negatively effect the complete database performance since the database has needs exclusive access to those memory structures and that causes waits.